# Getting Java Axis to work on Windows? NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, windows, web-services, axis

I'm trying to consume an ASP.NET Webservice from a Java application. The java app is being built with Eclipse on a Windows box. I've installed the Webservice tools for Eclipse and I've downloaded the Axis 1.3 files and extracted all of the supporting .jar files (axis.jar, saaj.jar, etc) into my java\lib folder.

My environtment variables are:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6;
CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib;

However, when debugging the project I get this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/AxisFault

The file it's happening on has "import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;" up top and that's as far as I've gotten. I'm VERY new to Java and come from a .NET C# background, so I'm a little fuzzy on whether you copy .jar files into the main java\lib folder or if they should be somewhere else. Everything I read on getting axis to work is for Apache Tomcat and setting up Webapplication folders and etc. I don't really need that as this is just a plugin module for Wowza and so the the jar file just gets execute by Wowza, but fails when trying to access the Webservice.

Is my classpath wrong, or am I missing something else? Any guidance would be great!

Comment: This is why I wish Eclipse had better support for the web services library that is built into Java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jar files are not added properly. Goto the project settings and add the axis jars as dependencies. Check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

Comment: Awesome - this is absolutely invaluable. Thanks so much.